# System $\dot x=Ax-|x|^2x$ has one limit ccle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have a system in $\mathbb R^2$, namely $\dot x=Ax-|x|^2x$ where $A$ is constant real matrix with complex eigenvalues $p+-iq (q>0)$.

I want to show that there exists at least one limit cycle for $p>0$ and none for $q<0$ using Dulacs Theorem and Poincare-Bendixson teorem, as seen here for exmaple http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/colin_sparrow/qtode/kitsonnotes.pdf

I cannot find an argument that uses this two theorems to conclude that such cycle must exist, may you can help me with that?

Comment: I do not have more information on $A$

Comment: I think there's a typo: should be two cases, $p > 0$ and $p< 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: Take $V(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_2^2$ and show that the infinity is always a repeller here. If $p>0$ conclude that the origin is unstable. Hence show that there is a positive invariant set that does not contain equilibria. Hence, by Poincare-Bendixson theorem...

Comment: Would do you mean with repeller here?

Comment: I mean that infinity "repels" orbits.